# constexpr condition not constant?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr

I wrote the following C++17 code:

```
constexpr bool gDebug = true;

template <typename T> constexpr const T& Select(const bool pCondition, const T& a, const T& b)
{
   if constexpr (pCondition)
   {
      return a;
   }
   else
   {
      return b;
   }
}
```

Then I called it like this:

```
int c = Select<QString>(gDebug, a, b); // In .cpp
```

I get `error: ‘pCondition’ is not a constant expression` for the `if constexpr` line.

Why? Shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why? Shouldn't this work?

No, it shouldn't. `pCondition` is not a [*constant expression*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression). I can see why this might be confusing, since `pCondition` is `const` - but the term constant expression refers to it being able to be evaluated at compile time. That is, not `const` but really `constexpr`.

Function parameters are not constant expressions. The fact that you happen to pass a compile-time constant is immaterial, since you could just as easily pass a runtime variable that you read from stdin or something.

`if constexpr` requires a constant expression, so you really just want `if` there. Or, you need to lift the condition to be a constant expression - such as by making it a template parameter:

```
template <bool pCondition, typename T>
constexpr const T& Select(const T& a, const T& b)
{
   if constexpr (pCondition) // now okay
   {
      return a;
   }
   else
   {
      return b;
   }
}

int c = Select<qDebug>(a, b);
```

or you could require that the parameter be a value encoded into a type:

```
template <typename Boolean, typename T>
constexpr const T& Select(Boolean pCondition, const T&, const T&);

constexpr std::true_type qDebug{}; // true_type, not bool = true
int c = Select(qDebug, a, b);      // okay
```

Comment: Actually I didn't expect the 'const bool' to do the trick. I expected the inline character of the constexpr function to be effective. I assumed the compiler would treat the parameter as constexpr during inlining.

Comment: @Silicomancer That would imply that you could pass in two different constexpr variables with different values into `Select<int>` and generate two entirely different functions.

Comment: Hmmm. What if I make the type of pCondition flexible, like 'typename T2' would that retain the constexpr feature of the gDebug argument?

Comment: @Silicomancer If by "flexible" you mean "deduced"? Then, no, that's the same thing - it'd still just deduce as `bool`. You would need to lift the value into the type system but using something like `true_type` and `false_type` instead - _then_ you could use it as an argument.

Comment: @Silicomancer That would mean that the function would only be callable with a constant expression as argument.

Comment: @Barry: Very interesting. After switching to true_type, I am getting a lot of useless "unreachable code" warnings. Seems I will implement your first solution (template parameter) after all.

Answer (score 1):

Barry is correct but I think it is not really where you are going wrong in your understanding.

```
template <typename T> constexpr const T& Select(const bool pCondition, const T& a, const T& b)
```

means that the function call is evaluable at compile time if the parameters are. But the function can be called with parameters not known at compile time. In this case the function call itself is not a constant expression and will be evaluated at run-time. It is still pure though in the sense of functional programming and it is `noexcept` by the way.

but `if constexpr (pCondition) {...` really means the expression must be evaluable at compile time.

Hence, because a constexpr function can be called with parameters unknown at compile time, it cannot contain expressions declared `constexpr` if they depend on those parameters.

Comment: Please tell me if I am wrong... using your logic I shouldn't get an error when declaring the function consteval instead of constexpr (in C++20), right? (because consteval functions can't be called with non-constant expressions)

Comment: @Silicomancer, I agree that according to my logic the if-statement is implicitly a constexpr if the function is declared consteval and it should not be an error making this explicit. But gcc does not agree and I think this is not bad because it forces people to be less verbose. My tired eyes thank gcc.

Comment: I think GCC should at least show a different error in that case, but well, yes, I can agree to eye protection :-)

Answer (score 0):

All other answers are correct, and not quite saying what I've wanted to know when tripping on this.  For a constexpr function to work in both constexpr (compile-time) and variable (runtime) contexts, you cannot have anything in the function that restricts it to constexpr context as Patrick points out.  More to the point, you don't *need* any such restriction for the function to work in constexpr context.  The compiler figures it out - it now has freedom (as required) to evaluate the function in either constexpr or runtime context.  So the `constexpr` in `if constexpr (pCondition)` can simply be taken out.